# How to create (predicate) for fetching data from DataTable using Express.call method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a DataTable in Home Controller as follows:

```
public DataTable GetTable()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(Info));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", new Info("India"), DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", new Info("UK"), DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", new Info("Bhutan"), DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", new Info("India"), DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", new Info("GreenLand"), DateTime.Now);
    return table;
}
```

Info class as follows

```
public class Info
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Info(string Add) {
        this.Address = Add;
    }
}
```

Now, i want to do the filtering operation based on Address Field, i.e Patient.Address

Here, Patient is object of Info class

I need to form the condition, in order to fetch the data.

I am forming condition using Express.call method

```
private static MethodCallExpression GetFieldCallExpression(Expression memExp, Type ColumnType, string ColumnName)
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(DataRowExtensions).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Field" && m.IsGenericMethod && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2 && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(string)).FirstOrDefault();
            var genericWrapper = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { ColumnType });
            var toLowerMethodCall = Expression.Call(
                 null,
                 genericWrapper,
                 memExp,
                 Expression.Constant(ColumnName, ColumnName.GetType())
                 );
            return toLowerMethodCall;
        }
```

Here, memExp - instance of DataRow
columnName - Patient.Address
columnType - string

[Predicate is formed as like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu9FC.png)

It got the message that,

"Column 'Patient.Address' does not belong to table ."

Where did i commit my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataRow` value accessors support only the "top level" column names (like "Dosage", "Drug", "Patient" etc. in your sample). In order to achieve your goal, you have to split the path and generate accessors manually.

For instance, the sample accessor for "Patient.Address" should be `dr.Field<Info>("Patient").Address` or in other words:

```
var value1 = dr.Field<Info>("Patient");
var value2 = value1.Address;
...
return value2;
```

Here is the same implemented generically:

```
private static Expression GetFieldValueExpression(Expression source, Type columnType, string memberPath)
{
    var memberNames = memberPath.Split('.');
    Expression value = Expression.Call(
        typeof(DataRowExtensions), "Field", new Type[] { columnType },
        source, Expression.Constant(memberNames[0]));
    for (int i = 1; i < memberNames.Length; i++)
        value = Expression.PropertyOrField(value, memberNames[i]);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, I have tried with your suggestion, i got the error, "System.ArgumentException: 'Address' is not a member of type 'System.String'" at value = Expression.PropertyOrField(value, ColumnNames[i]);

Comment: Hi Kalai, I guess you've passed `typeof(string)` as `columnType` while the procedure is expecting it to be `typeof(Info)` (basically the same used when creating the column)

Comment: HI Ivan, yes mistakenly i send the columntype of Patient as string, but it should Info class.